# Swift Alamofire callback causes database multithread access error

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, alamofire

I am using Alamofire.upload, and in encodingCompletion callback I want to update Database.

I am using DBManager.shared.database connection for every database access, but this seems to cause problem, because I get exception that multiple threads try to use same connection at the same time.

Are there some guidelines on how to use callbacks to prevent this kind of issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to synchronize your database access. The simplest way to to create a static `DispatchQueue` alongside your database singleton and dispatch all database accesses through that queue.

Edit: Something like:

```swift
final class DBManager {
    static let shared = DBManager()
    static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "your.identifier.here.DBManagerQueue")
}
```

Using it like:

```swift
... in a completion handler far far away ...
{ response in
    DBManager.queue.async {
        // Do something with the database
    }
}
```

However, a better solution would be to make all of this queuing internal to your `DBManager`, so that all users of it are always thread-safe. This is just a stopgap until you can perform such a refactor.

Comment: This sounds promising. I have found this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue.

Do you know of any online code examples with DispatchQueue and Swift on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some example code for posting data using Alamofire. I hope its easy to understand and helpful. Let me know if something is not clear.

```
func addProduct(token:String,product:Product, completion:@escaping( Error? )->Void)
{
    let addProductHeader:HTTPHeaders   = [
                                    "token":"\(token)",

                                        "Accept":"application/json"
                                       ]

    let addProductParameter:Parameters = [
                                          "name"        :   "\(product.name!)",
                                          "manufacture" :   "\(product.manufacture!)",
                                          "description" :   "\(product.descriptionField!)",
                                          "amount"      :   product.amount!,
                                          "quantity"    :   product.quantity!,
                                          "date"        :   "\(product.date!)"
                                         ]

    AF.request("Enter Your Server DB Link Here", method: .post, parameters: addProductParameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: addProductHeader).responseJSON
        {
            (response) in
            let encode = JSONEncoder()
            encode.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
            do
            {
                let jsonData = try encode.encode(product)
                print(jsonData)

                if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
                {
                    print(jsonString)
                }
                completion( nil )
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(error)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I have this already. Problem occurs if I access Database in the response function.

Comment: are you using guard let xyzzy else { return } ? code ?
can you show ur return code ?
Sometimes when you are using guard let ... your code might end before it runs full cuz if it finds data empty/nil it just runs return and ends the function

Comment: you did not answer the question